# Spring Boot JSP Resolution Error

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

So I've been playing around with Spring Boot and it's going fairly well. However, I've found myself in a weird situation and need help with it. All of my request mapping works with exception to one, for which I'm getting a `404`.

My project structure is:

> > +Project Name
> >       -`src/main/java`         - Code
> >       -`src/main/resources`    - Resources
> >       -`src/main/webapp/views` - Jsp Pages

**Important java code:**

```
Application.java

package com.demo.faisal;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.demo.faisal.model.Task;
import com.demo.faisal.service.TaskService;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan()
//@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo(TaskService taskService) {
        return (args) -> {
            // save a couple of customers
            taskService.addTask(new Task("Learn Java"));
            taskService.addTask(new Task("Learn Hibernate"));
            taskService.addTask(new Task("Learn Spring"));
            taskService.addTask(new Task("Learn SpringBoot"));

            // fetch all tasks
            log.info("Finding all tasks with getTasks():");
            log.info("-------------------------------");
            for (Task task : taskService.getAllTasks()) {
                log.info(task.toString());
            }
            log.info("");

            // fetch an individual customer by ID
            Task task = taskService.findTask(1L);
            log.info("Task found with findTask(1L):");
            log.info("--------------------------------");
            log.info(task.toString());
            log.info("");

            // fetch an individual customer by ID
            task.setDescription("Learn Java Done");
            log.info("Updated task description to: " + task.getDescription());
            taskService.updateTask(task);
            log.info("");

            // Updated task
            task = taskService.findTask(1L);
            log.info("Updated Task (1L):");
            log.info("--------------------------------");
            log.info(task.toString());
            log.info("");


        };
    }

}
```

Model:

```
package com.demo.faisal.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
//@Table(name = "${table_name})
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String description;

    public Task() {}

    public Task(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Task[id=%d, description='%s']", id, description);
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
package com.demo.faisal.model;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface TaskRepository extends CrudRepository<Task, Long> {

}
```

Service:

```
package com.demo.faisal.service;

import java.util.List;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.demo.faisal.model.Task;
import com.demo.faisal.model.TaskRepository;

@Service
public class TaskServiceImpl implements TaskService {

    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addTask(Task task) {
        taskRepository.save(task);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteTask(Long id) {
        Task task = taskRepository.findOne(id);
        taskRepository.delete(task);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void updateTask(Task task) {
        Task retrieved = taskRepository.findOne(task.getId());
        retrieved.setDescription(task.getDescription());
        taskRepository.save(retrieved);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Task findTask(Long id) {
        return taskRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Task> getAllTasks() {
        return (List<Task>) taskRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

MVC Config File (Replacement for web.xml):

```
    package com.demo.faisal.config;

    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
            configurer.enable();
        }

        @Bean
        public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
            InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/pages/");
            resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            return resolver;
        }

        @Override
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("/index");
        }   
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
package com.demo.faisal.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.demo.faisal.model.Task;
import com.demo.faisal.service.TaskService;

@Controller
public class TaskController {

    @Autowired  
    private TaskService taskService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/tasks", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getTasks() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("tasks");
        List<Task> tasks = taskService.getAllTasks();
        mav.addObject("tasks", tasks);

        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/taskform")  
    public ModelAndView showform() {
        return new ModelAndView("taskform","task",new Task());  
    }  

    @RequestMapping(value="/save",method = RequestMethod.POST)  
    public ModelAndView save(@ModelAttribute("task") Task task) {  
        taskService.addTask(task);;  
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/tasks");//will redirect to viewemp request mapping  
    }  

    @RequestMapping(value="/delete_task/{id}",method = RequestMethod.GET)  
    public ModelAndView delete(@PathVariable long id) {  
        taskService.deleteTask(id);;  
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/tasks");//will redirect to viewemp request mapping  
    } 

    @RequestMapping(value="/edit_task/{id}")  
    public ModelAndView update(@PathVariable long id) {  
        Task task = taskService.findTask(id);
        System.out.println("Returning taskeditform jsp with task: " + task.toString());
        return new ModelAndView("taskeditform","task",task);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/editsave",method = RequestMethod.POST)  
    public ModelAndView editsave(@ModelAttribute("task") Task task) {  
        taskService.updateTask(task);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/tasks");//will redirect to viewemp request mapping  
    }

}
```

**VIEW:**

```
taskform.jsp
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<h1>Add New Task</h1>
<form:form method="post" action="save" commandName="task">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Task Description :</td>
            <td><form:input path="description" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Update" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

taskeditform.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<h1>Edit Task</h1>
<form:form method="post" action="/editsave" commandName="task">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td><form:hidden path="id" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Task Description :</td>
            <td><form:input path="desciption" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Update" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

tasks.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<h1>Tasks List</h1>
<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />
<table border="2" width="70%" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="task" items="${tasks}">
        <tr>
            <td>${task.id}</td>
            <td>${task.description}</td>
            <td><a href="edit_task/${task.id}">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a href="delete_task/${task.id}">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
<br />
<a href="taskform">Add New Task</a>
```

From my controller, all of my RequestMappings work fine, except **/edit_task/{id}**.
Everytime I call this url, I hit the breakpoint and can see it returning a new `ModelAndView` with the view pointing to taskeditform.jsp

However, I get a `404` error saying it cannot find the view. The error message is below:

> type Status report
>
> message `/edit_task/WEB-INF/pages/taskeditform.jsp`
>
> description The requested resource is not available.

What I don't understand is the URL it's looking for : **`/edit_task/WEB-INF/pages/taskeditform.jsp`**. It looks like it is using the request mapping url and appending the view to it.

Can someone please point out what's going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the task model as well?

Comment: As a note, with Boot it's usual to put your templates in `src/main/resources/templates` instead of `webapp`. (This makes including resources from the classpath simpler.)

Comment: That only applies to technologies like Thymeleaf not plain JSP. Also when using JSP it is required to use WAR packaging (see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations) else it won't work. Add your `application.properties` and as stated make sure you have the proper packaging.

Comment: After editing your post, the error is pretty clear. Your configuration is wrong. Your prefix needs a leading `/` you have `WEB-INF/pages/` which should be `/WEB-INF/pages/`. I would suggest removing that configuration class altogether (you are using Spring Boot). and add `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/pages/` and `spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp` to your `application.properties`.

Comment: Thanks M.Deinum. That was it. Appreciate your help.

I also acknowledge your comments about removing the configuration class and using `application.properties`.